# how to map alt+hjkl in insert mode in vim with secureCRT?

Tags: vim, secure-crt

os: ubuntu16.04

tools: secureCRT 8.x

i tried many ways but failed, press alt+h/j/k/l will exit insert model to normal model.

like select session-option/terminal/emulation/emacs/use-alt-as-meta-key also dose not work.

Answer (score 0):

After a period of adaptation, I used to use the combination of crtl + hjkl